# One word for preparing (rubbing/polishing) marble tiles?

Tags: word-request

In India, at many places, floors are prepared with marble tiles or cemented floors with marble chips inside.

After fixing everything in floor once, floor is smoothed using rubbing sandpaper like materials and then polished to make shiny and further smooth.

I want to know one word for it.

Comment: I believe the term is "***surfacing*** marble", but a quick google didn't turn up any authoritative reference, so this will have to stay as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if people would use it in respect of "finishing" a marble floor, but ***to flat** (OED: To reduce to a plane surface; to reduce or obliterate the convexity, projections, or protuberances of)* can certainly be used when you're sanding down your initial rough work repairing car bodywork dents with epoxy resin filler, for example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Is "to flat" UK usage? I am unfamiliar with "to flat" in American English.

Comment: @kevinbatchcom: I've no idea *how* common it is, or where. I imagine the vast majority of BrE speakers are also unfamiliar with the usage. But they'd certainly *understand* it in context. And with things like this, which are obvious on the rare occasions when you do hear them, if you actually only heard it 2-3 times in a lifetime, would you actually "remember" it?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Perhaps my confusion stems from interpreting "to flat" as a verb. "Grind to flat" would make complete sense in context.

Comment: @kevinbatchcom: It's often *flat **down*** (or even more often, obviously, ***flatten***). But "verbification" is *such* a standard feature of English that you'd presumably be quite capable of encountering and understanding *"I clue crosswords"* even if you've never seen such a usage before. And you might well not take much notice of a *single* such usage, and subsequently maintain that ***to clue*** isn't a verb so far as you're concerned.

Comment: @JuliandotNut: For "cemented floors with marble chips inside", you may be referring to [**terrazzo**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrazzo).

Answer (score 1):

The process is called *finishing*. Polishing and honing are common [finishes](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/marble-finishing-techniques-35342.html). See this commercial [page](http://www.percocomarble.com/finishes.php) for examples of several more types of stone surface finishes.

Merriam-Webster has this [definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/finish):

> **finish** (noun) 1.c: the final treatment or coating of a surface

Answer (score 1):

Popularly, it is known as ***Tile Sanding and Rubbing*** among ceramic professionals.

Tile sanding and rubbing is the procedure that makes the tiles smoother and shinier. This is commonly done when the tiles are new OR when they are too old and need servicing.

On the market, you find *[Tile sanding and rubbing stone](http://www.homedepot.com/p/QEP-Tile-Sanding-and-Rubbing-Stone-with-Dual-Grit-Surfaces-10022Q/100037081)* for DIY purpose. However, in India, where I live, we use machine.

Comment: While I feel this is the right answer, I will wait if someone can come up with a better answer with reference.

And yes, I am looking for something done with machines as you mentioned.

Comment: The linked "tile sanding and rubbing stone" is for sanding the rough **edges** of ceramic tile at the time of installation. It does not appear to be intended for sanding the tile **surface**.

Comment: @JuliandotNut: In your question, "after fixing everything in floor once" suggests you are referring to the process of installing the floor. Also, your question specifically mentions marble. _Ceramic_ tiles are generally not sanded, and are maintained differently from _marble_ and _stone_. If you are specifically looking for the process of maintaining a marble floor, michelle's answer has the proper word, "to burnish" or "burnishing".

Comment: @kevinbatchcom : NO, burnishing is only the last step (same as polishing). Practically, as I have seen myself, it is a 7 step process with floor getting smoother every step. Burnish/Polish is in the last 2 steps. Tile Sanding seems proper as intermediate steps do involve sand papers on the machine. The first step involves rougher plate at the machine and 7th is the smoothest.

Comment: I had an opportunity to build and supervise two houses! **And** in them both, I asked for sanding and rubbing on flooring containing various types of tiles *including* marble. I'm pretty sure this in India; no idea about any other dialect.

Comment: @kevinbatchcom that **stone** is used for sanding and rubbing edges but I'm talking about the *nouns* themselves!

Answer (score 0):

The verb you are looking for, I believe, is "to burnish". Burnishing is usually done with a machine similar to a buffer. Rather than a buffing pad, though, it uses an abrasive pad to polish the stone and give it a high gloss.

Comment: I believe _buffing_ and _burnishing_ are techniques to maintain the appearance of an installed floor, while _finishing_ refers to preparing the surface when it is first installed. The process of finishing will likely include buffing or burnishing.

Comment: What @kevinbatchcom said. I think *burnishing* is more like *polishing* - it's all about making "matt" surfaces "glossy", not making an uneven surface *flat*.

Comment: Fair enough! Based on the title of the question, I thought that was the step he was looking for "Preparing (rubbing/polishing) marble tiles"), but maybe you are correct and he needs the step prior to that.

Comment: This vendor has several [examples](http://www.grainger.com/category/burnishers/equipment/cleaning/ecatalog/N-cpb?redirect=Burnishers) of floor burnishing machines. The same vendor sells many varieties of burnishing/buffing/polishing/cleaning/stripping [pads](http://www.grainger.com/category/floor-machine-pads/equipment/cleaning/ecatalog/N-cpj?bc=y) for use with the floor machines.

Comment: @michelle : Your answer helped but it is the finishing step. I need word for complete procedure, including steps prior to burnish.

Comment: Burnishing *generally* happens on the wooden floor. It's for smoothing and shining both.